# Something doesn't work. What did I do wrong, if anything? How can I solve my issue?

Tags: ms-access, logic, operators

Last weekend I created on my home computer with Access a database containing only one table, "People", which contained the following field: "First name", "Last name", "Gender", "Date of birth", "Race", "Civil status", "Blood type" (I generated the records through fakepersongenerator).
Now, I wanted to write a query with SQL which printed the first name, the last name, the gender and the date of birth of people whose first name contained a y or had an i as its last but one letter. This is the code as I wrote it:

```
SELECT "First name", "Last name", "Gender", "Date of birth"
FROM "People"
WHERE "First name" LIKE '%y%' OR "First name" LIKE '%i_'
```

The records corresponding to people whose first names are Brain, Bonnie and Collin don't get printed. I brought this problem before my teacher yesterday and he advised me to invert the subconditions (i. e. write WHERE "First name" LIKE '%i_' OR "First name" LIKE '%y%'), which I did that evening, but I got the same result. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: show us your data so we can find out it.

Comment: The condition `"First name" LIKE '%i_'` obviously doesn't work. The `_` wildcard does work in MS-SQL, but probably not in other types of databases. The question of scaisEdge is therefore quite important.